# Confusion in solving $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Given 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 1 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
b = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 100 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Trying to calculate x for Ax = b

$$ Ax = b \Longleftrightarrow A^{T}Ax = A^{T}b \Longleftrightarrow x = (A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}b $$

$$ 
A^{T}A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1 &
  0 \\0 & 1 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ (A^{T}A)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ (A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T} = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ \therefore x =  \begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 100 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 51 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}$$

substituting x in Ax and calculating Ax gives

$$ Ax = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 1 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 51 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 51 \\ 4 \\ 51 \end{bmatrix} \ne b$$

How come matrix calculations didn't give any inconsistency as there is no solution for x in Ax=b

I understand that $\begin{bmatrix} 51 \\ 4 \\ 51 \end{bmatrix}$ is projection of b in column space of A

updated:

$Ax = b \implies A^{T}Ax = A^{T}b \implies x = (A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}b $ to $ Ax = b \Longleftrightarrow A^{T}Ax = A^{T}b \Longleftrightarrow x = (A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}b $

Comment: if your calculations are accurate then what you’d got is that $\|Ax-b\|$ is minimal and can be verified by the use of calculus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrows in
$$ Ax = b \implies A^{T}Ax = A^{T}b \implies x = (A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}b $$
point from left to right, but not from right to left. In particular, the first step is not necessarily reversible (for example when all entries in $A$ are $0$).

Comment: could you explain or point to some resource explaining why $Ax=b \Longleftrightarrow A^{T}Ax = A^{T}b$ is wrong

Comment: @junnu $A^{T}Ax = A^{T}b \implies Ax = b$ only holds when $A^{T}$ is invertible, but in your case it is clearly not invertible.

Comment: @junnu you don't need matrices to understand why you cannot always undo that step, just take $A=0$ and $b=1$.